# How can I enter a workflow at an arbitrary step

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow service that links a Workflow Foundation 4 process with an application database which stores records that show what step our users must complete next. In the event of a non-resumable error in the workflow, it will make it so that the workflow is unable to be resumed, but the database entries that are in the application still exist, so there is a "disconnect" between workflow state and our application state.

What I would like to do is create another instance of the failed workflow, but get it into sync with the application database entries. That would entail going to an arbitrary entry point in the workflow based on the application database entries that exist.

Is it possible to do this? Are there any pitfalls to doing so? Is there a better way to manage the workflow to application dependency?

The workflow would look something like this:

1. Start the workflow. This creates an application db record that tracks the progress of the process and a db record that shows the user what needs to be done next.
2. The user "works" the step, which does a call into the workflow service (using receive/sendreply), updating the db record with the outcome of the work, and moving to the next step in the workflow.
3. Step 2 repeats with all the various steps creating db records to be worked, then updating those records with the results of being worked and creating new db records to be worked, until the process completes.

The question I'm trying to answer is if the user gets to a certain step in the process and the workflow engine fails so that the workflow instance is not resumable, how might I use the application db entries to "restart" the process to re-enter the process, skipping to the point of failure (assuming we had resolved the issue that caused the failure in the first place). This would eliminate the user having to "redo" work that had already been done, and stay in the process.

What I thought was that if there was a way of looking at the application database records that have been created to determine where the process had died, if I could "skip" previously finished steps and move to the point in the workflow that failed based on those db records, I could "resume" the process (from the user's point of view) without causing rework.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just starting out with Workflow and I've been watching some videos on channel9 at MSDN and I came across one that may help you out.
It talks about using Bookmarks and some Task based-API by Ron Jacobs.

Check it out at: [Workflow TV - WF4 Workflow Episodes - a Task Based API](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Workflow-TV/endpointtv-WF4-Workflow-Episodes-a-Task-Based-API)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to implement is Compensation- that is, custom rollback functionality built into a transaction. Here's the start of the Transaction and Compensation activity documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358756.aspx

You can use the Compensate activity to do database cleanup after a failed transaction.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but, actually, probably not - unless I really do not understand compensation. These are potentially long running processes that would create many application database records, many of which were successfully worked as far as the application is concerned. Undoing that would be bad for our users.

But - I could be really misunderstanding some important parts of the process of creating these workflows so that they are resiliant and never cause the workflow itself to fail. That may be the real key.

Comment: Yeah, if it's a long series of changes, you'll want your workflow to exit gracefully. Either that, or have your application leave a "paper trail", so that there's a changelog for the app to associate with each long-running transaction that can be cleaned up using a transaction ID...